# How to use external JavaScript file in PHP documents?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, wordpress

My JavaScript files don't seem like it is linked to my PHP file.

I am building a WordPress website. I have header.php and calling this header.php file by including

in my main.php file. I added JS path in the head tag in header.php, but it doesn't seem like it's working(the JS files I added are for a carousel, but does not change anything). I just started learning so I can't even guess what I am doing wrong here. What can I do to link my JS files?

- header.php, main.php, and js folder are in the root folder. Javascript files are in the js folder.

-- This is how I linked JS file in header.php. inside of the head tag

```
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lightslider.js"></script>
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
```

Comment: Have you checked the browser's Developer Console? Any error occurred?

Comment: That's not how WordPress works. Also, be careful to add jQuery to WordPress, which might clash with the WordPress structure. Read [this](https://wpengine.com/resources/jquery-wordpress/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WordPress, you can either add JavaScript files via a WordPress theme or plugin.

To link the JS from WordPress theme, you can use:

```
wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer);
```

Similiarly, to link CSS from WordPress theme, you can use:

```
wp_enqueue_style( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $media );
```

Detailed usage can be found [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/).

---

For WordPress plugins, you can add the following in your main theme file:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','init');

function init() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'test-js', plugins_url( '/js/test.js', __FILE__ ));
}
```

As mentioned in the comment above, you shouldn't include jQuery without careful consideration.

Comment: I found out a different way to fix the problem, but your answer helped a lot! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

to fix this you can try adding that script at the end of the page and try this instead

```
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <script  src="js/Jquery.js"></script>
    <script  src="js/lightslider.js"></script>
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
```

just removed

```
type="text/javascript"
```

from it and it will work for sure

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but it didn't work... I included the script tags at the end of the main.php and before the body tag ends in footer.php. Both didn't work. I seriously don't know what to do.

Comment: The answer is not related. The `type="text/javascript"` is optional.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

whenever you add any JS file add some unique number function after the extension.you can use timestamp because it change everytime.

Just like following.(**example is for PHP & Javascript**)

Because of `cache` sometimes it happens that your code doesn't change.

```
<script src="my_js_file.js?v=<?=time()?>" ></script>
```

also if you are windows user just press `CTRL + SHIFT + R` key to hard refresh the browser to clear cache

Comment: This question is specifically asking about including JS files in WordPress and isn't about cached files. While this answer may be useful for other questions, it isn't an appropriate answer for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try to put a `slash` character in the front to make an absolute path like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/Jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/lightslider.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of adding js files to your WordPress theme is enquing them in functions.php like below

```
wp_enqueue_script ('jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.js', '', '3.3.1', true);
wp_enqueue_script ('globaljs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js', '', '', true);
```

You also don't need to add your own jQuery since WordPress ships with jQuery already. All you need to do is call it like so:

```
wp_enqueue_script ('jquery');
```

You can read more about the parameters here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

Answer (score 0):

You need to enqueue that js file in your theme's functions.php file.

```
function my_load_scripts($hook) {

    // create my own version codes
    $my_js_ver  = date("ymd-Gis", filemtime( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'js/custom.js' ));
    $my_css_ver = date("ymd-Gis", filemtime( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'style.css' ));
    
    // 
    **wp_enqueue_script( 'custom_js', plugins_url( 'js/custom.js', __FILE__ ), array(), $my_js_ver );**
    wp_register_style( 'my_css',    plugins_url( 'style.css',    __FILE__ ), false,   $my_css_ver );
    wp_enqueue_style ( 'my_css' );

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_load_scripts');
```